# Updating values in async await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have developed this little piece of code that gets the current lat and lon and pass them to the Google Map URL for fetching map data.

The lat and lon variables are set initially to undefined and then their value is updated when navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is called. This function does return the data correctly via the position object. Somehow however the values of the variables are not updated and they remain undefined when they are passed to the URL.

Where is the problem?

```
const getLocationDetails = async () => {

    let lat = undefined;
    let lon = undefined;

    await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( position => {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
    });
    const res = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lon}`,
        { method: 'GET' });
    const response = await res.json();

};
```

Comment: `position.coords.latitude` is this already present or takes some time to get populated ? Just make a new async function which will return values. and use that while defining `let lat = asynfunction();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) doesn't return a promise, so `await` is a no-op there and the function does not pause waiting for the operation `getCurrentPosition` starts to complete. Execution just continues right away¹ when you `await` something that isn't a promise.

Instead, give yourself a promise-enabled version of it:

```
const asyncGetCurrentPosition = options => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
});
```

then use it:

```
const getLocationDetails = async () => {
    let {coords: {latitude, longitude}} = await asyncGetCurrentPosition();
    const res = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}`,
        { method: 'GET' });
    // Note: Missing a `res.ok` check here
    const response = await res.json();
};
```

(The `let {coords: {latitude, longitude}} = ..` part of that is *destructuring assignment* taking `coords.latitude` and `coords.longitude` and putting them in `latitude` and `longitude` variables, respectively. Then I've updated the `fetch` to use `latitude` and `longitude` [instead of `lat` and `lon`]. Could also use `const` here, since you don't change `latitude` and `longitude`. Matter of style.)

---

¹ When I say *"continues right away"* above, that's a bit of an overstatement. The code after the `await` is scheduled to be run in the microtask queue when the current task (or microtask) is complete. So there's a *brief* delay, but it doesn't wait for `getCurrentPosition` to finish its work. That's the main point.